# Distance Calculation Between Two Address

Tags: javascript, html

Hey plz help me to find out distance between two address... 
I have a code but its not always working With Eclipse and Tomcat Server,, It Works 2 out of 15times..But It works on Normal Editor Like DreamWeaver
Problem is that at the time of window loading the map display then its shows error icon with no error messages.. 
Please Help me to Find out this..I have to use this code so please help me to correct this code.. 
Followings are my code and Error output snap.

Many Many Thanks In Adv....

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Distance Matrix service</title>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        width: 50%;
      }
      #content-pane {
        float:right;
        width:48%;
        padding-left: 2%;
      }
      #outputDiv {
        font-size: 11px;
      }
    </style>
    <script>
    <!--
var map;
var geocoder;
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var markersArray = [];

//var origin1 = new google.maps.LatLng(55.930, -3.118);
var origin;
var destination;
//var destinationB = new google.maps.LatLng(50.087, 14.421);

var destinationIcon = 'https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=D|FF0000|000000';
var originIcon = 'https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=O|FFFF00|000000';

function initialize() {
  var opts = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(9.93123, 76.26730),
    zoom: 10
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), opts);
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
}

function calculateDistances() {
  origin = document.getElementById('source').value;
  destination = document.getElementById('dest').value;
  var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
  service.getDistanceMatrix(
    {
      origins: [origin],
      destinations: [destination],
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
      unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
      avoidHighways: false,
      avoidTolls: false
    }, calcDistance);
}

function calcDistance(response, status) {
  if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
    alert('Error was: ' + status);
  } else {
    var origins = response.originAddresses;
    var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;
    deleteOverlays();

    for (var i = 0; i < origins.length; i++) {
      var results = response.rows[i].elements;
      addMarker(origins[i], false);
      for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
        addMarker(destinations[j], true);
        outputDiv.innerHTML +=   results[j].distance.text  + '<br>';
      }
    }
  }
}

function addMarker(location, isDestination) {
  var icon;
  if (isDestination) {
    icon = destinationIcon;
  } else {
    icon = originIcon;
  }
  geocoder.geocode({'address': location}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      bounds.extend(results[0].geometry.location);
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: results[0].geometry.location,
        icon: icon
      });
      markersArray.push(marker);
    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: '
        + status);
    }
  });
}

function deleteOverlays() {
  for (var i = 0; i < markersArray.length; i++) {
    markersArray[i].setMap(null);
  }
  markersArray = [];
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
//-->
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content-pane">
      <div id="inputs">
 <label>Source</label><input type="text" name="source" id="source" /> 
 <label>Destination</label><input type="text" name="dest" id="dest" />
        <p><button type="button" onclick="calculateDistances();">Calculate
          distances</button></p>
      </div>
      <div id="outputDiv"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

OutPut Like this.Click on Error Output to see---....

[Error Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9D8Pv.jpg)

Comment: Where are you including your API Key?

Comment: @Novice in above code I have not included api key .. but it works on another editor DW every single time.. so i think for the given script api doesn't nedded... but in Eclipse and Tomcat server it get prob... You can see my error output..